# Matrix mapping error in vertex shader code in DirectX9

Tags: hlsl, directx-9

In my DirectX9 sample when I do the below things all works fine and I get the desired rotating triangle on screen,

[image: without shaders]

```
g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj );
g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_VIEW, &matView );
g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld );
```

But when I try to do the same using shaders nothing gets rendered

```
D3DXMATRIXA16 matWorldViewProj = matWorld * matView * matProj;
constantTable->SetMatrix(g_pd3dDevice, "g_mWorldViewProjection", &matWorldViewProj);
//Vertex Shader snippet
Output.Position = mul(In.Position,g_mWorldViewProjection);
```

when I made below change in the vertex shader

```
Output.Position =  In.Position;
```

I get the static triangle rendered on the screen.

[image]

What could be the probable error in my code/technique ?

(
profile: vs_3_0 using D3DXCompileShaderFromFile
)

Comment: Have you tried to change `D3DXMATRIXA16 matWorldViewProj = matWorld * matView * matProj;` to `D3DXMATRIXA16 matWorldViewProj = matProj * matView * matWorld ;`. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Yes, tried the same, but it did not help. Nothing gets rendered.

Comment: Looks like the problem is somewhere else. Can you provide some more code, please? The whole shader and your drawcall would be interesting. If its to long, you could use pastebin and link it.

Comment: Here it is code and both shaders.I have pasted all 3 in single page you have to extract and keep the vertex shader as vertex.vsh and pixel shader as pixel.psh file. [CODE LINK](http://pastebin.com/Uuzfmayu)

Comment: Maybe the matrix isn't set in the vertexshader. You overwrite your variable `constantTable` at the compilation of the pixelshader. So your matrix would be only set in the pixelshader.

Comment: I do not think so because the usage of the variable `constantTable` is correct. Something else is going wrong.

Comment: It looks like you used this [tutorial](http://www.two-kings.de/tutorials/dxgraphics/dxgraphics18.html) and there at the compilation of the pixelshader the parameter of the constantTable is set to null. It would override your pointer, so you only set the constants in the pixelshader.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20122/discussion-between-ppu-and-gnietschow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the compilation of the pixelshader you overwrite your variable `constantTable`. So the matrix is only set in the pixelshader and not in the vertexshader. Either you declare an additional variable `constantTablePix` or set the parameter to `NULL` if you dont need to pass information to the pixelshader.

The correct order for the matrix is. (I never get the order right, but it works now :) )

```
D3DXMATRIXA16 matWorldViewProj = matWorld * matView * matProj;
```